# How to receive more messages from Serial Port c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am using `System.IO.Ports`.
I send messages to device and want to wait for all messages from it.

I am trying do it like this:

```
message = Console.ReadLine();
_serialPort.Write(message);
Console.WriteLine(_serialPort.ReadExisting());
```

But it returns only the first line. 
I have tried using `port.BytesToRead`, but I get the same results.
When I use `ReadLine()` it doesn't return anything.

Edit:

To see all line use Event handler.

Solution for my problem is use \r (enter) on the end line.

Comment: You should keep reading. Not all bytes are directly present.

Comment: You cannot wait for all input to have arrived. You have no way of knowing when it will be done.

Comment: Use the `DataReceived` event, it handles all of this for you.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: The problem was in I missed /r (enter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReadExisting return the available bytes available at the exacte time, put a delay befor you read the buffer, a work around would be

```
message = Console.ReadLine();
_serialPort.Write(message);
Thread.Sleep(200);
Console.WriteLine(_serialPort.ReadExisting());
```

Edit 2 :
here is how i do it on my projects

```
private SerialPort port;
string DataReceived  = string.Empty;

public string OpenPort(string PortName, int BaudRate)
    {
        // if the port is already used by other window then return the same instance
        if (port != null)
            if(port.IsOpen)
                return "True";


        port = new SerialPort(PortName, BaudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        // Attach a method to be called when there
        // is data waiting in the port's buffer
        port.DataReceived += new
            SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

        // Begin communications
        try
        {
            port.Open();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
        return "True";
    }


private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
Thread.sleep(200);
            DataReceived =  port.ReadExisting();
        }
```

in your main

```
message = Console.ReadLine();
_serialPort.Write(message);
//use Stopwatch to calculate time befor you can exit from the loop
while(true)
{
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DataReceived))
break;
// Todo : Check stopwatch for timeout
}
```

Comment: Ok, maybe it will helpful, but now it doesnt work from another reason. And it at last only return the same messages what i send.

Comment: DataReceived throw exception does not exist

Comment: But it also return only messages which i send ;/

Comment: you should declar it as string , refere to the editedanswer

Comment: great, line terminator is usually a line break, but in your case its an Ok.

Comment: So bad i am noob. It now it only work, but when i start commend by putty which write something every one second. And after it, I open it in visual. So problem maybe is in send messages. But when i do that lights blink. And when i send messages which isnt comend is should write "Exception".
However thanks for your help though. I will fight with this tomorrow :)

Comment: The problem was in I missed /r (enter).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a new line issue expected from your serial device try:

```
message = Console.ReadLine();
_serialPort.WriteLine(message);
Console.WriteLine(_serialPort.ReadExisting()); # try debug here replace with string test = _serialPort.ReadLine();
```

Comment: It only return messages which i send ;/ It should send the same messages as a first one but no in all cases. I didnt check it.

Comment: You can give this a try _serialPort.serialPort.DiscardInBuffer() before you read data from serial.

Comment: You've mentioned that you tried using _serialPort.BytesToRead. Try clean the buffer using _serialPort.DiscardInBuffer after receiving the required bytes.

Comment: It nothing give me. Maybe i should project this string?